# Bootstrap filter table multiple word

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, filter, html-table

I need a filter that's capable of getting more than one word.

```
<input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search">
<table class="table border table-hover table-light small table table-striped mt-2">
    <tr>
        <td>Deo grada</td>
        <td>Ulica</td>
        <td>Sprat</td>
        <td>Oprema</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td class="text-dark">deo</td>
            <td class="text-dark">adresa</td>
            <td class="text-dark">spratova</td>
            <td class="text-dark">oprema</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

//script code that I found for bootstrap

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myTable tr").each(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can try to check jquery plugin https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Filter-Html-Table-with-Multiple-Criteria-multifilter/

Comment: Thank you, very interesting solution